# Can't include external javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this website. If I try to include the JavaScript I have between the  as an external file, the slider doesn't work.
So I take this

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

And I move it to an external file like below

```
<script src="MyScript.js"></script>
```

Contents of MyScript.js

```
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
```

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="half.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/845d55b72b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>


<!--info section-->
<section class="infoslide">
<div class="notes">
  <i class="fas fa-code fa-6x"></i>
</div>


  <div class="slider">



<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>1. JavaScript</h2>
    <p >This slider is created using JavaScript</p>
  </div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <h2>2. Web layout</h2>
  <p > I only created the web layout here. No real content to de displayed. </p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <h2>3. And the last one</h2>
  <p >Donec vel efficitur ipsum, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel efficitur ipsum. In nulla ante.</p>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left fa-2x"></i></a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-2x"></i></a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

</div>

</section>



</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
html {
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: rgb(243, 243, 243);

}

body {

  margin: 0px 0px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    /*background-image: url(top.png) ;*/

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center , center right;
    background-size: contain;


}


  .infoslide {
    display:grid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    grid-template-columns: 33.3% auto 33.3%;


    grid-template-areas:
    'one two tree' ;
  }
.notes {
  grid-area: one;
}

.slider {
  grid-area: two;
}

/*html*/

* {box-sizing: border-box}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(243, 243, 243);
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
float: left;
padding: 15px;
color:  rgb(33, 95, 153);

  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* On hover */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {

  color: rgb(182, 176, 165);
}


h2 {color: rgb(40, 40, 175);}
p {color: rgb(117, 115, 115);}
```

Comment: I don't see the MyScript.js in your HTML, only as a comment above. You have to add it to have it working.

Comment: Done. Is the same I have between the script tags

Comment: I don't mean the content of the file, I mean where you inserted it inside your html. I don't see `<script src="MyScript.js"></script>` inside your HTML file. It matters where you put it in your HTML.

Comment: Between the body tags.

I tested it again and it works, only nothing is displayed until you start pressing the arrows. There is the problem.

If the script is inside the html it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried adding `<script src="MyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. That sometimes works, just identifying the language of the script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the script tag and its contents from you HTML file. Add the script tag above your body closing tag, your HTML file shoud look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="half.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/845d55b72b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>


<!--info section-->
<section class="infoslide">
<div class="notes">
  <i class="fas fa-code fa-6x"></i>
</div>


  <div class="slider">



<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>1. JavaScript</h2>
    <p >This slider is created using JavaScript</p>
  </div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <h2>2. Web layout</h2>
  <p > I only created the web layout here. No real content to de displayed. </p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <h2>3. And the last one</h2>
  <p >Donec vel efficitur ipsum, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel efficitur ipsum. In nulla ante.</p>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left fa-2x"></i></a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-2x"></i></a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>

</div>

</section>


<script src="MyScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then add the Javascript code into a file named "MyScript.js" which needs to be in the same folder/directory as you html file is inside of.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the code `<script src="MyScript.js"></script>` just before the closing body tag in your HTML.

This ensures that the script is loaded and executed directly after the rest of your page, and all the elements on it, have been loaded.

```html
<head>

  ...

</head>


<body>

  ...

  <script src="MyScript.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere else